# Eliminar valores con False de una lista de diccionarios. Python

Tags: python-3.x, django, lista, diccionarios

Tenia unos datos como estos:

```
bloques =  [
            {'Capacitacion': False}, 
            {'Articulos': True}, 
            {'Proyectos': True}, 
            {'Libros': True}, 
            {'GradoAcademico': True}
          ]
```

Eliminaba los valores que tienen `False` en este caso `Capacitacion` eso lo hacia con esto:

```
bloqueOrdenApi = [bloqueOrden for bloqueOrden in bloques if list(bloqueOrden.values()) != [False]]
print("bloqueOrdenApi------->>>>>>>>>>>", bloqueOrdenApi)
```

Lo que me daba como resultado los valores solo con `True`. Que es lo que estoy buscando.

Pero tuve que modificar mi data de `bloques` y ahora tuve que agregar un campo llamado `ordenPersonalizable` y me quedó así:

```
bloques =  [
            {'Capacitacion': False, 'ordenPersonalizable': 5}, 
            {'Articulos': True,     'ordenPersonalizable': 1}, 
            {'Proyectos': True,     'ordenPersonalizable': 4}, 
            {'Libros': True,         'ordenPersonalizable': 2}, 
            {'GradoAcademico': True, 'ordenPersonalizable': 3}
          ]
```

Estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo de eliminar los valores que tengan `False` en este caso `Capacitacion` para ello hago lo mismo de antes:

```
bloqueOrdenApi = [bloqueOrden for bloqueOrden in bloques if list(bloqueOrden.values()) != [False]]
print("bloqueOrdenApi------->>>>>>>>>>>", bloqueOrdenApi)
```

Pero me devuelve todos los datos de un inicio y no se elimina el valor con `False`:

```
[{'Capacitacion': False, 'ordenPersonalizable': 5}, 
{'Articulos': True, 'ordenPersonalizable': 1}, 
{'Proyectos': True, 'ordenPersonalizable': 4}, 
{'Libros': True, 'ordenPersonalizable': 2}, 
{'GradoAcademico': True, 'ordenPersonalizable': 3}]
```

Me gustaría poder eliminar los valores con `False`. Cómo lo puedo hacer? Agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo aquí tienes ambas soluciones, una con comprehensions y otra con funciones lambda:

```py
bloques =  [
    {'Capacitacion': False, 'ordenPersonalizable': 5},
    {'Articulos': True,     'ordenPersonalizable': 1},
    {'Proyectos': True,     'ordenPersonalizable': 4},
    {'Libros': True,         'ordenPersonalizable': 2},
    {'GradoAcademico': True, 'ordenPersonalizable': 3}
]

# comprehensions
bloqueOrdenApi = [item for item in bloques if list(item.values())[0]]
print(bloqueOrdenApi)

# lambda
bloqueOrdenApi2 = list(filter(lambda item: list(item.values())[0], bloques))
print(bloqueOrdenApi2)
```

Comment: Sin explicación tu respuesta no tiene valor. Tal vez funcione, tal vez le sirva al OP, pero a nadie más.

Comment: La explicación es explícita, ya está en la pregunta, 'solo que aquí en la respuesta es modificada y obvia, las funciones lambda y comprehensions es lo más sencillo que existe!